# How to troubleshoot No Sound on CentOS 6.4 w/ USB headset?

Tags: centos, usb, audio

Have a new Dell machine with a fresh install of CentOS 6.4.

I have a headset hooked up via USB, but no sound.

I'm not sure CentOS is recognizing my sound card -- or maybe it's not recognizing the USB headset?

Card and headset are listed in /proc/asound/cards:

```
[root@Azaz07 asound]# cat cards
0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xf7d10000 irq 30

1 [USB            ]: USB-Audio - Plantronics .Audio 478 USB
                      Plantronics Plantronics .Audio 478 USB at usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3, full speed
```

I successfully followed the steps [here](http://www.linwik.com/configuring_the_audio_and_updating_alsa_for_centos_and_rhel_6) to install kmod-alsa, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

I also tried to install "Sound and Video" as a group package, [as detailed here](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/PluginsFor64BitFirefox), but got an error:

```
[root@Azaz07 ~]# yum groupinstall "Sound and Video"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.sonic.net
 * elrepo: elrepo.org
 * extras: centos.mirror.freedomvoice.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: mirror.pac-12.org
Setting up Group Process
Checking for new repos for mirrors
Warning: Group Sound and Video does not exist.
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

What should I check / troubleshoot from here to get my USB headset working?

Comment: I'd boot a newer livecd (OpenSUSE, Fedora, ....), get the lspci output and maybe the dmesg of that machine and paste it somewhere. Since the machine is new, chances are a more recent kernel like ones included with the distributions above will work.

Comment: What does the sound preferences look like? See my A for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### lsusb

First thing to try is make sure that the device shows up when plugged in.

#### Example

I have a Logitech headset.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:0a01 Logitech, Inc. USB Headset
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:c521 Logitech, Inc. Cordless Mouse Receiver
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 17ef:1003 Lenovo Integrated Smart Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

You can find out more about it by enabling the `-v` switch to `lsusb`.

#### Example

```
$ lsusb -v | less
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:0a01 Logitech, Inc. USB Headset
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x046d Logitech, Inc.
  idProduct          0x0a01 USB Headset
  bcdDevice           10.13
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          318
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
...
```

#### dmesg

Next check that the hardware shows up as being detected correctly via `dmesg` output.

```
$ dmesg
...
[237717.191322] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, address 3
[237717.387495] usb 2-1.1: new low speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
[237717.482484] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c521
[237717.482487] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[237717.482489] usb 2-1.1: Product: USB Receiver
[237717.482491] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[237717.488818] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/input/input10
[237717.488955] generic-usb 0003:046D:C521.0003: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input0
[237717.495771] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.1/input/input11
[237717.495984] generic-usb 0003:046D:C521.0004: input,hiddev96,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input1
[240126.944155] usb 2-1.2: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 6
[240127.034731] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0a01
[240127.034735] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[240127.034738] usb 2-1.2: Product: Logitech USB Headset
[240127.034740] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[240127.232622] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
```

#### Sound preferences

Under the speaker applet in GNOME you can access the sound preferences for your system. Make sure that the speakers are selected as the active output device.

[image: applet]   [image: prefs menu]

[image: sound prefs dialog]

Comment: Yeah, dmesg seems to have some strange output.  usb 1-1.3: new full speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.3: New USB device found...
usb 1-1.3: Product: Plantronics .Audio 478 USB
usb 1-1.3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
input: Plantronics Plantronics .Audio 478 USB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.3/input/input7
generic-usb 0003:047F:C011.0004: input,hiddev96,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Device [Plantronics Plantronics .Audio 478 USB] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input3
ALSA urb.c:831: cannot submit datapipe for urb 0, error -28: not enough bandwidth

Comment: You got it with your last update.  The output apparently doesn't automatically switch over to the USB headset in sound preferences, once I switched it manually it did work. Is there a way to access those preferences via command line though?

Comment: @some1 - gets me every time too 8-)

Comment: You can use the commands to list the sinks: `pacmd "list-sinks"`. Once identified you can use a command like this to set the output: `pacmd "set-default-sink alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Logitech_USB_Headset-00-Headset.analog-stereo"`.